# Calling a function re instantiate the class

Tags: python-3.x

When I call this function

```
self.myplot = self.plot(x ='X', y ='Y', kind ='scatter')
```

from a class inheriting from pandas.DataFrame, instead of executing the function, it reinstantiates the class, creating an infinite recursive reinstantiation.

```
import pandas as pd

class ChildDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    myplot = None

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return ChildDataFrame


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self['X'] = [2,3]
        self['Y'] = [3,4]

        print('Dataframe: \n',self)
        self.myplot = self.plot(x ='X', y ='Y', kind ='scatter')    

a=ChildDataFrame()
```

How I should call the function, and why it reinstantiates the class?

If I move the plot() call outside of the class, it also reinstantiate the class multiple times

```
import pandas as pd

class ChildDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    myplot = None

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return ChildDataFrame


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self['X'] = [2,3]
        self['Y'] = [3,4]

        print('Dataframe: \n',self)

a=ChildDataFrame()
a.plot(x ='X', y ='Y', kind ='scatter')
```

gives this output:

```
Dataframe:
    X  Y
0  2  3
1  3  4
Dataframe:
    X  Y
0  2  3
1  3  4
Dataframe:
    X  Y
0  2  3
1  3  4
```

Comment: First line of class, shouldn't it be `self.myplot = None` ?

Comment: @TheSHETTY-Paradise that would raise an error

Answer (score 0):

Look at the below description, I hope this would help and you can refer to [this link](http://mrsenko.com/blog/atodorov/2016/09/14/beware-of-recursion-loop-when-using-super/)

```
class Base(object):
    def method(self):
        print 'original', type(self), self.__class__

class Derived(Base):
    def method(self):
        print 'derived', type(self), self.__class__
        super(type(self), self).method()
        # super(self.__class__, self).method()

class Subclass(Derived):
    def method(self):
        print 'subclass of derived', type(self), self.__class__
        super(Subclass, self).method()
```

When you call Derived().method() the result is

```
derived <class '__main__.Derived'> <class '__main__.Derived'>
original <class '__main__.Derived'> <class '__main__.Derived'>
```

Here both shortcuts are evaluated correctly. However when you call Subclass().method() the result becomes

```
subclass of derived <class '__main__.Subclass'> <class '__main__.Subclass'>
derived <class '__main__.Subclass'> <class '__main__.Subclass'>
derived <class '__main__.Subclass'> <class '__main__.Subclass'>
derived <class '__main__.Subclass'> <class '__main__.Subclass'>
... skip ...
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

In the example the call super(Subclass) works fine and invokes Derived.method() as expected. Then we call super(Subclass) inside Derived.method() which leads back to where we were hence the recursion loop. The problem is only visible when you have other classes that inherit from a class which uses incorrect invocation

Comment: If  you mean that it is a bug in the DataFrame class, I mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @yoyaxema that is what the possibility is as what i have shared with you, is a analysis of that problem and that analysis show us the same thing.